# Getting full file name with extension

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I have a method that should return the file name and file size returned from the contentResolver based on a selected file `URI`, however at times the file that was chosen has no extension. I am looking for a way to get the full file name with its extension or a way to determine the file type somehow. Below is my method I currently have

```
    //This is the intent which triggers the file choosing
    Intent fileIntent = new Intent(  );
    fileIntent.setType( "*/*" );
    fileIntent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
    fileIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true );
    startActivityForResult( fileIntent, REQUEST_CODE_FILE );

    //Method in onActivityResult
    Uri selectedFile = intent.getData();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String fileName = null;
    int fileSize = 0;
    try {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query( selectedFile, null, null, null, null );
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        fileName = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME ));
        fileSize = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( OpenableColumns.SIZE ) );
    }catch( Exception ex ){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if( cursor != null ) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to get the full file name with its extension

`OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` does not have to be a filename.

> or a way to determine the file type

Call `getType()` on the `ContentResolver`, supplying the `Uri`. This should return a valid MIME type for the `Uri`.

Comment: I see, so  to be clear there is no real way to get the full file name with extension via `ContentResolver`? Thanks for the suggestion on the `getType()`.

Comment: @kabuto178: Please understand that the `Uri` might not be a file. What you are asking is equivalent to "how do I force a Web server to give me the full file name with extension for a URL?" The answer is, you can't, in part because the URL might not point to a file. Instead, it might be something dynamically generated. The same thing holds true for `Uri` values on Android.

Comment: I see, I will have to be a bit creative in this case then to retain the name and extension. Cheers