# Content resolver returning incorrect file name

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to get the actual file name of a video file that was downloaded from another application (Fiverr). The file is selected using media store, as shown below:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

This is how I get the name of the file:

```
private static String getFileName(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String[] projection = {OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error - ", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I open my devices Gallery application, the name of the file is `exampleVid.mp4`, but when I open media store to select the video file the name is `Fiverr` (without an extension).

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25701598/11951642) answer that says `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME does not have to be a filename.`, but in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info) it says that this is how to get a file name that is associated with a content URI.

---

Can someone please clarify how I should be handling this and perhaps provide an article or example of how to correctly retrieve a file name from a URI?

Comment: Your second documentation link is referring specifically to a `Uri` that is served by `FileProvider`, which is not the case for your `Uri`. "how to correctly retrieve a file name from a URI?" -- there is no "correctly". A `Uri` does not have to represent a file or anything that ever had a filename.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for taking the time to reply. How is it that the gallery application of my device shows the correct name of the file? Or when I select the file from my device itself instead of selecting it directly from the Downloads directory?

Comment: "How is it that the gallery application of my device shows the correct name of the file?" -- they use the `MediaStore`, most likely. "Or when I select the file from my device itself instead of selecting it directly from the Downloads directory?" -- I have no idea what "select the file from my device itself" means. But, in general, different `Uri` values may have different providers, and they may implement things differently, including what they return (if anything) for `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`. Your results will vary by device model, OS version, or even from user-installed apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare "they use the MediaStore, most likely." Can you please elaborate? Do you mean using `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` instead of `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`?

Comment: "Do you mean using `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`" -- that would be my guess. Note that a gallery app is not using `ACTION_PICK`. It queries the `MediaStore` to find the media to display in the gallery, and it presumably includes `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` in that query as one of the values to return (along with MIME type, etc.). I have not tried getting `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` for a `Uri` returned from `ACTION_PICK`. I presume that there is a recipe for that.